# Detecting microphone blow

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, microphone, avaudiorecorder

I'm in the process of developing an app that allows children to complete breathing exercises as part of their physiotherapy process, at the moment I am still just trying to confirm the microphone is picking up the blowing sound. I am getting the following message in the NSLog

```
2017-04-22 17:01:52.292319+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.322377+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.352402+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.382331+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.412318+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.442277+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.472358+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.502275+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.532323+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.562265+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
2017-04-22 17:01:52.592255+0100 microphone[2251:596932] Mic blow detected
```

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                          AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless],
                          AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],
                          AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],
                          AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];

NSError *error;

recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

if (recorder) {
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder record];
    levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(levelTimerCallBack:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
} else
    NSLog(@"%@", [error description]); 
}

- (void)levelTimerCallBack:(NSTimer *)timer {
[recorder updateMeters];

const double ALPHA = 0.05;
double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (0.05 * [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;

if (lowPassResults < 0.000005)
    NSLog(@"Mic blow detected");
}

@end
```

I originally had "if (lowPassResults < 0.95)" but no mic blow was detected at all. The issue I'm having now is that it's detecting Mic blow without anyone blowing into the mic. I am thinking the value (0.00005) is still too high but cannot find the appropriate value. Can anyone advise on what it is I need to be adjusting here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not have a self calibration procedure as part of the start up process?  I.e.  Talk now, blow hard now, blow gently now, quiet now, repeat.  Threshold = average between blow gently and quiet.

Comment: @zipzit could you explain what you mean by this? sorry I am new to Xcode